# how do i get token balance and send token on BEP20?

Tags: web3js, binance

Hi i have came out my code but i am not sure i am anywhere near

what i am trying to achieve is

1. Getting the balance of token of Token eg(BNB)
2. Sending token after connected to metamask to another wallet for purchase eg. To another wallet address
3. Which i have this busd token contract which i always get 0 where i have 5 busd in my metamask

any advise would be appreciated!

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Connect to crypto wallet</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.7.4-rc.1/web3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<script>
/* To connect using MetaMask */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    if (window.ethereum) {
        connect();
    } else {

        //show connect button
    }

});


async function connect() {
  if (window.ethereum) {

     await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

     // var Web3 = require('web3');
     const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');

     //window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
     const account = web3.eth.accounts;

     //Get the current MetaMask selected/active wallet
     const walletAddress = account.givenProvider.selectedAddress;
     
     console.log(`Wallet: ${walletAddress}`);
     //alert(walletAddress);

     const bnbToken = "0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52";
     const ibgTokenContract = "0x5c46c55A699A6359E451B2c99344138420c87261";
     const busdTokenContract = "0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56";

     web3.eth.getBalance(busdTokenContract).then((value) =>{
        console.log('Busd '+value);   
     });


  } else {
   console.log("No wallet");
  }
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Connect Wallet" onclick="connect();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 web3.eth.getBalance(busdTokenContract)
```

Here you're trying to get the BNB balance of address 0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56. If you want the BUSD balance of another address, you need to instantiate the BUSD contract somewhere in your code, then call its balanceOf() function. Reading https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/ might help.

Comment: what i mean is i need to get my balance instead of the token balance of (busd)